# Return rows with duplicate value in column if one of the rows contains specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to query against a table to determine where a value is assigned multiple times but one of assignees must equal a determined value.

For example :

```
EmployeeName  |EmployeeNumber|EmployeeDept|EmployeeBadgeCode|
--------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+
Dante Hicks   |1             |200         |1                  pair A
Randall Graves|5             |201         |2                            no pair
Brody Bruce   |1             |555         |3                  pair A
Banky Edwards |20            |004         |4                  pair B
Gwen Turner   |7             |200         |5
Holden McNeil |20            |450         |1                  pair B  
TS Quint      |5             |105         |10                           no pair
```

I want to return where all rows where there is a duplicate EmployeeNumber but only if one of the duplicate's value is 1 for EmployeeBadgeCode.

So I would want to return 'Dante Hicks' and 'Brody Bruce' as one pair of duplicates and 'Banky Edwards' and 'Holden McNeil' as another pair of duplicates.

'Randall Graves' and 'TS Quint' would not be returned because they have duplicate EmployeeNumber but neither of EmployeeBadeCode values are equal to 1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not completely sure I'm following.  What defines a duplicate, the `EmployeeNumber`?  If so, then both results would have to contain 1 for them to be duplicates.  Anyhow, a `join` with `group by/having` should get you what you're after.  What have you tried?

Comment: Your questions isnt clear regarding what a duplicated is. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Sorry... A duplicate occurs when EmployeeNumber appears more than once. I did a group by in my attempt... My query returns all duplicates, I'm having the difficulty in getting to return just rows where one of the duplicates equals 1.

Comment: sorry but doesnt make sense, Why you have different EmployeeName with same `number = 1` ?? You question is when are duplicates and one of those is 1, but if are dupicates, then both are 1?? And if that is the case what happen when 3 employee has 1?

Comment: I'm modifying the question... I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: looks like you miss an important part on the first question.

Comment: What happen if both duplicates has 1 on Badge field? Also you should include the format of desire output. is both name in a row, or each name in a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43a58/3)**

```
e1.[EmployeeName] < e2.[EmployeeName]
```

This is to make sure you dont try to match with yourself and also avoid reverse pair.

```
SELECT e1.*, e2.*
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2
  ON e1.[EmployeeNumber] = e2.[EmployeeNumber]
 AND e1.[EmployeeName] < e2.[EmployeeName]
WHERE 
    e1.EmployeeBadgeCode = 1
or  e2.EmployeeBadgeCode = 1
```

In this solution both employess can have `1`. You need add one aditional validation if want only one of the employee be `1`

**OUTPUT**

```
|  EmployeeName | EmployeeNumber | EmployeeDept | EmployeeBadgeCode |  EmployeeName | EmployeeNumber | EmployeeDept | EmployeeBadgeCode |
|---------------|----------------|--------------|-------------------|---------------|----------------|--------------|-------------------|
|   Brody Bruce |              1 |          555 |                 3 |   Dante Hicks |              1 |          200 |                 1 |
| Banky Edwards |             20 |            4 |                 4 | Holden McNeil |             20 |          450 |                 1 |
```

Comment: Thanks, Juan.  This worked out.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will return both those rows. If there was only one EmployeeNumber 1 then it would not return anything.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE EmployeeNumber =
    (SELECT EmployeeNumber
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE EmployeeNumber = 1
    GROUP BY EmployeeNumber 
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```